# How to write a text to end of generated pdf doc using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

Using `PDPageContentStream` I am able to place the image and text at the top of the generated pdf page, but I am not able to place the the text to the end of pdf document. 
How do I get the exact x, y values for invoking moveTextPositionByAmount(x,y)? See the sample code below

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();  
PDXObjectImage img = new PDJpeg(document, new FileInputStream("F:/Project/demo_logo.jpg"));  
PDPage imagePage = PDFUtility.addNewPage(document);  
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, imagePage);  
contentStream.beginText();  
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 14);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(10, 680);
contentStream.drawString("Budget Report");  
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.drawImage(img, 10, 700);
float yStartNewPage = imagePage.findMediaBox().getHeight() - (12 * 10);
float tableWidth = imagePage.findMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * 10);
boolean drawContent = true;
float yStart = yStartNewPage;
float bottomMargin = 500;
BaseTable table  = new BaseTable(yStart,yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, 10, document, imagePage, true, drawContent);
.............generating reports using table(BaseTable)..............
table.draw();
File file = new File("F:/project/demo.pdf");
Files.createParentDirs(file);
resultArray.put(file.getAbsolutePath());
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 14 );
/* reports are generating dynamically, i cannot give value to x and y */
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, y);
contentStream.drawString("End Of Report");
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();
document.save(String.valueOf(file));
document.close();
```

Comment: You could start by making this even remotely readable.

Comment: I suspect the answer to the question is 0,0 :-)

Comment: *reports are generating dynamically* - then report generation has to return the final y coordinate.

Comment: My comment was before the reformatting... I think what was Naveen wants to know is how to get the current y position from the contentStream, e.g. something like getCurrentCursorPosition(). Answer: there isn't. You need to manage this yourself. I can't find it, but somewhere here is an answer to somebody who wanted to know when to start with a new page, this is somewhat related.